# How to Grab Google Client ID when GA3 and GA4 are both on the same page

Tags: cookies, google-analytics-4, clientid

I currently have a page where Google Analytics 3 and Google Analytics 4 both exist on the same page, and are setup via GTM. I need to retrieve the client ID for each independently. What is unclear to me though is if they actually each have an independent ID when used on the same page? I want to confirm that for sure, but I'm not sure if this verifies it or not.

If I look at the list of trackers on the page using this code, I will get a full object for the first console.log with the UA- ID of the GA3 tracker, but an undefined for the 2nd. It does not appear this is picking anything up for GA4.

```
    ga(function(tracker) {
      var trackers_multi = ga.getAll(); 
      console.log("Trackers1: " + JSON.stringify(trackers_multi[0]));
      console.log("Trackers2: " + JSON.stringify(trackers_multi[1]));
    });
```

But if I check the cookies in chrome dev tools > application > cookies and search for "_ga" I only get one _ga cookie.  Does this confirm that they really do only share a single client ID? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Have you activated GA4 inside your webpage? have you installed Ga4 ? you should put the related code immidiately after <head> and as long as I am concerned ga is a function related to universal analytics and if you wanna do the same thing in GA4 the related function would be gtag. please have a look at this link https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/event-parameters?client_type=gtag